# Create user with list of data

Tags: java, arrays, object

The program should contain the customers plus a list of the calories and the distance during the week.

My question is, how can I put together the customer's name and the distance?

```
public class TestCustomer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> customersNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        char userInput = ' ';

        System.out.println("A to show all");
        userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);

        if(userInput == 'A') {
            System.out.println("All results ");
            for(int i = 0; i < customersNames.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(customersNames.get(i));
            }
        }
 }
```

And here's my Customer class

```
public class Customer {
private String name;
private double calories;
private double distance;

public Customer(String name, double distance) {
    this.name = name;
    this.distance = distance;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setCalories(double calories) {
    this.calories = calories;
}
public double getCalories() {
    return calories;
}

public void setDistance(double distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}
public double getDistance() {
    return distance;
}
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this it is an requiremen to have "ArrayList<String> customersNames" otherwise I would use an "ArrayList<Customer> customers" instead and simply put everything in there?

Comment: So your program will have 3 options: **Add Customer**, **Show Customers** and **Search Customers**?

Comment: @nemohack Ok. Now I understand. Let me get back to you.

Comment: I don't see you storing the day-of-week. Tip: [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a list of customers instead of customernames.
I put the Customer class as static in the testclass for brevity(keep everything in one file). Better  to have it seperate as you do.

Also I did not want to change the whole design or do a complete rewrite - it is your design. So this is only making it work, fixing the behavior to the one required.

Eg with having the customers in HashMap that is indexed by name one could retrieve a dataset more elegantly in O(1). But thats maybe another improvement.

This only has the list. So for simplicity I added an equals, that makes users equal if they have the same name.

I create a new User that can be searched in the list. If not found I add this user with the given input to the list. 
If found I search for existing the user in the list with indexOf and retrieve that existing user. I do it in one step.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestCustomer {

    public static class Customer {

        private String name;
        private double calories;
        private double distance;

        public Customer(String name, double calories, double distance) {
            this.name = name;
            this.calories = calories;
            this.distance = distance;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setCalories(double calories) {
            this.calories = calories;
        }

        public double getCalories() {
            return calories;
        }

        public void setDistance(double distance) {
            this.distance = distance;
        }

        public double getDistance() {
            return this.distance;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 5;
            hash = 71 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            return Objects.equals(this.name, ((Customer)obj).name);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

        char userInput = ' ';

        while (userInput != 'q') {
            System.out.println("Press 'a' to show all customers or press 's' to search for customer ");
            userInput = scan.next().charAt(0);
            userInput = Character.toUpperCase(userInput);

            if (userInput == 'A') {
                System.out.println("Here's the list of all customers: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(customers.get(i).getName());
                }
                // here I should show the list of all customers and their data
            } else if (userInput == 'S') {
                System.out.println("You selected to search for a customer");
                createCustomer(customers);
            }
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Customer> createCustomer(ArrayList<Customer> customers) {
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter customer's first name: ");
        String fName = scan2.next();
        System.out.println("Enter customer's last name: ");
        String lName = scan2.next();
        String fullName = fName + " " + lName;
        Customer newCustomer = new Customer(fullName,0,0); 
        if (customers.contains(newCustomer)) {
            newCustomer=customers.get(customers.indexOf(newCustomer));
            System.out.println("Customer already on the list. Here's the information: ");
            System.out.println(fullName + " " + newCustomer.distance + " " + newCustomer.calories );
        } else{
            System.out.println("Customer not found. Would you like to create a new customer? y/n ");
            char createUserPrompt = scan2.next().charAt(0);
            if (createUserPrompt == 'y') {
                String[] daysOfWeek = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
                for (String daysOfWeek1 : daysOfWeek) {
                    System.out.println("Enter calories consumed on " + daysOfWeek1);
                    newCustomer.calories = scan2.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Enter distance walked on " + daysOfWeek1);
                    newCustomer.distance = scan2.nextDouble();
                }
                customers.add(newCustomer);
            } else if (createUserPrompt == 'n') {
                System.out.println("User will not be added.");
            }
        }
        return customers;
    }
}
```

sample run:

```
Press 'a' to show all customers or press 's' to search for customer 
a
Here's the list of all customers: 
Press 'a' to show all customers or press 's' to search for customer 
s
You selected to search for a customer
Enter customer's first name: 
kai
Enter customer's last name: 
last
Customer not found. Would you like to create a new customer? y/n 
y
Enter calories consumed on Monday
5
Enter distance walked on Monday
5
Enter calories consumed on Tuesday
5
Enter distance walked on Tuesday
5
Enter calories consumed on Wednesday
5
Enter distance walked on Wednesday
5
Enter calories consumed on Thursday
5
Enter distance walked on Thursday
5
Enter calories consumed on Friday
5
Enter distance walked on Friday
5
Enter calories consumed on Saturday
5
Enter distance walked on Saturday
5
Enter calories consumed on Sunday
5
Enter distance walked on Sunday
5
Press 'a' to show all customers or press 's' to search for customer 
a
Here's the list of all customers: 
kai last
Press 'a' to show all customers or press 's' to search for customer 
s
You selected to search for a customer
Enter customer's first name: 
kai
Enter customer's last name: 
last
Customer already on the list. Here's the information: 
kai last 5.0 5.0
Press 'a' to show all customers or press 's' to search for customer
```

Comment: if printed out. it does see testrun.. But yes you may need to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

With some modifications to your `Customer` class in which the `calories` and `distance` will be stored ad an array for each day,

An `ArrayList<Customer>` will be used to store the list of customers.

Possible solution:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    private static Scanner scan;
    private static ArrayList<Customer> customers;

    public static Customer customerExists(String customerName) {
        for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
            if (customers.get(i).getName().equals(customerName)) {
                return customers.get(i);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void addCustomer() {
        System.out.println(">> Add Customer <<\n");

        System.out.print("Enter customer's first name: ");
        String fName = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter customer's last name: ");
        String lName = scan.nextLine();

        String fullName = fName + " " + lName;

        Customer existingCustomer = customerExists(fullName);

        if (existingCustomer != null) {
            System.out.println("\nCustomer already on the list. Here's the information: ");
            System.out.println("#\tName\t\tCalories [Mon-Sun]\t\t\t\t\t\tDistance [Mon-Sun]");
            System.out.println(existingCustomer.getName() + "\t" + Arrays.toString(existingCustomer.getCalories()) + "\t" + Arrays.toString(existingCustomer.getDistance()));
            return;
        }

        String[] daysOfWeek = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
        double calories[] = new double[daysOfWeek.length];
        double distance[] = new double[daysOfWeek.length];

        for (int j = 0; j < daysOfWeek.length; j++) {
            System.out.print("Enter calories consumed on " + daysOfWeek[j] + ": ");
            calories[j] = scan.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter distance walked on " + daysOfWeek[j] + ": ");
            distance[j] = scan.nextDouble();
        }

        Customer customer = new Customer(fullName, calories, distance);

        customers.add(customer);

        System.out.println("\nCustomer added successfully!\n");
    }

    public static void showCustomers() {
        System.out.println(">> All Customers <<\n");
        System.out.println("#\tName\t\tCalories [Mon-Sun]\t\t\t\t\t\tDistance [Mon-Sun]");

        for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i+1 + "\t" + customers.get(i).getName() + "\t" + Arrays.toString(customers.get(i).getCalories()) + "\t\t\t" + Arrays.toString(customers.get(i).getDistance()));
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public static void searchCustomers() {
        System.out.println(">> Search for a Customer <<\n");

        System.out.print("Enter customer's full name: ");
        String fullName = scan.nextLine();


        Customer customer  = customerExists(fullName);
        System.out.println(fullName);

        if (customer == null) {
            System.out.println("\nNo such customer exists.\n");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("\nCustomer information:\n");
        System.out.println("#\tName\t\tCalories [Mon-Sun]\t\t\t\t\t\tDistance [Mon-Sun]");
        System.out.println(customer.getName() + "\t" + Arrays.toString(customer.getCalories()) + "\t" + Arrays.toString(customer.getDistance()) + "\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean cont = true;
        int option = -1;

        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        customers = new ArrayList<>();

        do {
            System.out.println("=== Select an Option ===");
            System.out.println("1. Add a customer");
            System.out.println("2. Show all customers");
            System.out.println("3. Search for customer");
            System.out.println("0. Exit");

            System.out.print("\n  > ");

            try {
                option = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

                System.out.println("\n");

                switch(option) {
                    case 1:
                        addCustomer();
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        showCustomers();
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        searchCustomers();
                        break;

                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("Good Bye!");
                        cont = false;
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.err.println("'" + option + "' is not a valid option. Please try again.\n");
                        break;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("Invalid option selected.\n");
            }

        } while (cont == true);
    }
}
```